# Cordova Geolocation works sometimes and other times not

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation

I'm developing an Ionic app which uses `Geolocation` to get the coordinates of the current location. Recently found out that `Geolocation` works most of the times outside in an open area but when in closed rooms, it isn't functioning properly. I tried to change some settings, such as setting `enableHighAccuracy` to `True` and `False` but it doesn't solve the issue. Any suggestions how to get `Geolocation` to work in closed rooms?

Answer (score 0):

We also faced this same problem in one of our hybrid mobile application. It will work in Open Wifi Network. But it won't work in closed/secured wifi network. You need to talk to admin to enable google map URL as whitelist one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that is not entirely my issue since it works with the WiFi when I go close to a window. It is very strange

Comment: Then it might be a signal issue. Similar to we can't able to hear the voice when we are speaking through mobile in particular place.

Answer (score 0):

> Common sources of location information include Global Positioning
>   System (GPS) and location inferred from network signals such as IP
>   address, RFID, WiFi and Bluetooth MAC addresses, and GSM/CDMA cell
>   IDs.
>   https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-geolocation/

GPS will often not work indoors, you can try to compare the positioning with another app at the same location. In addition to GPS other methods are supported, depending on your use case you might be able to incorporate RFID / Bluetooth beacons.